# filter product list follow condition in custom module magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, filter, condition

> ```
> public function createCollection()
> {
>     /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
>     $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
> ```

```
    if ($this->getData('store_id') !== null) {
        $collection->setStoreId($this->getData('store_id'));
    }

    $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
        ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
        ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1));

    $conditions = $this->getConditions();
    $conditions->collectValidatedAttributes($collection);
    $this->sqlBuilder->attachConditionToCollection($collection, $conditions);

    /**
     * Prevent retrieval of duplicate records. This may occur when multiselect product attribute matches
     * several allowed values from condition simultaneously
     */
    $collection->distinct(true);

    return $collection;
}

/**
 * Get conditions
 *
 * @return \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine
 */
protected function getConditions()
{
    $conditions = $this->getData('conditions_encoded')
        ? $this->getData('conditions_encoded')
        : $this->getData('conditions');

    if ($conditions) {
        $conditions = $this->conditionsHelper->decode($conditions);
    }

    foreach ($conditions as $key => $condition) {
        if (!empty($condition['attribute'])
            && in_array($condition['attribute'], ['special_from_date', 'special_to_date'])
        ) {
            $conditions[$key]['value'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($condition['value']));
        }
    }

    $this->rule->loadPost(['conditions' => $conditions]);
    return $this->rule->getConditions();
}
```

I found solution in core `magento/catalogwidget/block/product`. How do I filter product list follow condition in custom module.